Why for Samson are Nazarite Prohibition(s) Framed in Terms of Tumah?
(Rambam, Laws of Nezirut, 3:13)
שִׁמְשׁוֹן לֹא הָיָה נָזִיר גָּמוּר. שֶׁהֲרֵי לֹא נָדַר בְּנָזִיר אֶלָּא הַמַּלְאָךְ הִפְרִישׁוֹ מִן הַטֻּמְאָה. וְכֵיצַד הָיָה דִּינוֹ. הָיָה אָסוּר בְּיַיִן וְאָסוּר בְּתִגְלַחַת וּמֻתָּר לְהִטָּמֵא לַמֵּתִים. וְדָבָר זֶה הֲלָכָה מִפִּי הַקַּבָּלָה:
"Samson was not a nazirite in a complete sense, for he never took a nazirite vow. It was merely that the angel caused him to be separated from impurity.
What were the laws applying to him? He was forbidden to drink wine and cut his hair. He was, however, permitted to incur impurity due to contact with the dead. This concept is a halachah transmitted by the Oral Tradition."
Question - to make the point that the angel separated him … why not just say  אֶלָּא הַמַּלְאָךְ הִפְרִישׁוֹ period. Or
אֶלָּא הַמַּלְאָךְ הִפְרִישׁוֹ מן הדברים האסורים לנזיר. What's this business about טומאה?
The Rambam doesn't mean normative טומאה. Shimshon, per Chazal, was permitted tumas hameis. And the pasuk in his story that refers to 'Tumah' וְאַל־תֹּאכְלִ֖י כָּל־טָמֵֽא per Chazal was a prohibition directed at eating grapes and grape products - the things that he could not eat. It was not a reference to the prohibition of drinking wine or shaving. Drinking and shaving do not use the word Tumah - וְאַל־תִּשְׁתִּ֖י יַ֣יִן וְשֵׁכָ֑ר
Yet the Rambam makes no mention of the one activity that the pasuk uses the word Tumah for - eating - in this הַמַּלְאָךְ הִפְרִישׁוֹ מִן הַטֻּמְאָה law!
Rambam seems to see Tumah as a broad concept which encompasses everything that Shimshon could not do … seems to cover hair and eating prohibited grape products (even though he does not discuss this) and drinking wine. But how are any of these activities -  Tumah?
You might say that since the pasuk labels one (eating grape products) of the objects of these prohibited Shimshon activities as tamei, the Rambam saw fit to utilize the same term to cover several activities (although for some reason he left the main one out - eating). But this logic simply begs the question. Why did the Pasuk in Shoftim choose the word - טמא - for prohibited eating when the Torah in Nasa uses no such word for eating (see below)?
The whole idea seems counterintuitive. The elephant in the room. The normative Tumah that we are used to seeing isn't a problem for Shimshon, but somehow - via the pasuk narrowly (eating) and the Rambam more broadly (drinking and hair and eating (although he makes no mention of eating))- frame all this as 'Tumah.' Misnomer? What gives?
In Parshat Nasa the Nazir prohibitions of eating and drinking and shaving are NOT framed in terms of Tumah:
מִיַּ֤יִן וְשֵׁכָר֙ יַזִּ֔יר חֹ֥מֶץ יַ֛יִן וְחֹ֥מֶץ שֵׁכָ֖ר לֹ֣א יִשְׁתֶּ֑ה וְכׇל־מִשְׁרַ֤ת עֲנָבִים֙ לֹ֣א יִשְׁתֶּ֔ה וַעֲנָבִ֛ים לַחִ֥ים וִיבֵשִׁ֖ים לֹ֥א יֹאכֵֽל׃
they shall abstain from wine and any other intoxicant; they shall not drink vinegar of wine or of any other intoxicant, neither shall they drink anything in which grapes have been steeped, nor eat grapes fresh or dried.
כׇּל־יְמֵי֙ נֶ֣דֶר נִזְר֔וֹ תַּ֖עַר לֹא־יַעֲבֹ֣ר עַל־רֹאשׁ֑וֹ עַד־מְלֹ֨את הַיָּמִ֜ם אֲשֶׁר־יַזִּ֤יר לַיהֹוָה֙ קָדֹ֣שׁ יִהְיֶ֔ה גַּדֵּ֥ל פֶּ֖רַע שְׂעַ֥ר רֹאשֽׁוֹ׃
Throughout the term of their vow as nazirite, no razor shall touch their head; it shall remain consecrated until the completion of their term as nazirite of יהוה, the hair of their head being left to grow untrimmed.
Only when we get to actual Tumas Meit do we see:
לְאָבִ֣יו וּלְאִמּ֗וֹ לְאָחִיו֙ וּלְאַ֣חֹת֔וֹ לֹא־יִטַּמָּ֥א לָהֶ֖ם בְּמֹתָ֑ם כִּ֛י נֵ֥זֶר אֱלֹהָ֖יו עַל־רֹאשֽׁוֹ׃
Even if their father or mother, or their brother or sister should die, they must not become defiled for any of them, since hair set apart for their God is upon their head:
*But,for Shimshon, as discussed, the proscription(s) are characterized as הִפְרִישׁוֹ מִן הַטֻּמְאָה ... why?
I am beginning to suspect that the Rambam's הַמַּלְאָךְ הִפְרִישׁוֹ מִן הַטֻּמְאָה might go beyond drinking wine and eating grapes and shaving ... it may even mean that God wanted Shimshon to see many things in terms of Tumah or Tahara and thus avoid Plishti women and saving himself with a jawbone for that very reason:
Sota 9b:
״וַיִּבְקַע אֱלֹהִים אֶת הַמַּכְתֵּשׁ אֲשֶׁר בַּלֶּחִי״. אָמַר רַבִּי יִצְחָק דְּבֵי רַבִּי אַמֵּי: הוּא אִיוָּה לְדָבָר טָמֵא — לְפִיכָךְ נִתְלוּ חַיָּיו בְּדָבָר טָמֵא.
After Samson smote one thousand Philistines with the jawbone of a donkey, he called the place Lehi, and God miraculously granted him to drink, as he was dying of thirst. The verse states: “But God cleaved the hollow place that is in Lehi, and out of there came water; and when he had drunk, his spirit came back, and he revived” (Judges 15:19). Rabbi Yitzḥak of the school of Rabbi Ami says: He desired something unclean, as he was driven by lust to Philistine women. Therefore, the saving of his life was dependent on something unclean, the jawbone of a donkey.
=======

But we do find in Nasso that if he becomes tamei, it says ki tamei nizro. His status has been contaminated. (Neizer is a personal status that is actually somewhere between a gavra and a cheftza -- or even "the gavra is the cheftza.") So here, though the prohibition on touching corpses is lifted (for obvious reasons), the angel is making clear it is not a "half-price" or "less-than" nezirus.
